# How do I set tilde expansion in zsh?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I am trying to achieve expansion of the tilde into the $HOME variable with zsh, and was wondering what best practice is in this case?

Basically what I want is that:

```
$ ls ~
```

on pressing TAB expands to

```
$ ls /home/myusername
```

where `HOME=/home/myusername`. The `_tilde` function usually does a ldap search, followed by named dirs, followed by the dir stack, none of which I need.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `~` is part of path expansion; why do you need to tab-complete it?

Comment: I use several different $HOME variables on different machines, I like seeing which one is active on the machine I am using at the moment.